# AutoLayout: when to use bottomLayoutGuide vs. "V:[continueButton(50)]|"

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm having a UIViewController inside a UIPageViewController, where I would like to add a button at the very bottom.

I just don't understand the difference between

```
NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[button]|", options: .DirectionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: nil, views: ["button":button]) // works
```

and

```
NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:[button][bottomLayoutGuide]", options: .DirectionLeadingToTrailing, metrics: nil, views: ["button":button, "bottomLayoutGuide":bottomLayoutGuide]) // doesn't work
```

The first line adds the buttom at the very bottom, with the second line there is a padding of 50px between the button and the bottom. Does this have to do with the UIPageViewController (which itself is in a UINavigationController)?

Comment: On the surface, the difference is that `|` means "the button's superview", while `bottomLayoutGuide` means "the view controller's bottom layout guide". Those are completely different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bottom layout guide is useful for layouts where the parent controller has some kind of view that overlays the current view controller's contents. So in your case the `UIPageViewController` has such a view, which is a `UIPageControl` view that you may not want to be overlapped, thus if you specify the bottom layout guide as a boundary, your view will pin right above the `UIPageControl`. That's convenient especially if you depend on such a constraint (that becomes clear in the example I provide below).

A `UITabBarController` also has a bottom layout guide, which is the tab bar's top. This is convenient because most of the times you'll need a constraint to the top of the tab bar otherwise views will be situated underneath it (which may lead to bad user experience [think: If you constrain a tableView to the very bottom (**NOT** the bottom layout guide) then the last cell may be overlaid by the tab bar, which is certainly bad UX]). So as you can see sometimes it is useful to have the ability to constrain to the bottom layout guide of a view controller where the parent controller's elements occupy space that may not be necessarily good to place a view under.

Same goes for `UINavigationController`, if you have a view controller contained in a `UINavigationController`, the `topLayoutGuide` will basically indicate where the `UINavigationController`s navigation bar ends, thus it would be useful to constrain any views to that top layout guide otherwise the views will end up underneath the navigation bar.

In your case I think you'll be fine constraining your views to the very bottom of the `UIPageController`'s view as views underneath a `UIPageControl` usually contain images which will not look obfuscated by the `UIPageControl` (The page control serves more as a visual feedback mechanism than an interaction element).

As **matt** pointed out in his comment by doing something like `V:[button]|`, you are basically constraining the view to the very bottom of its superview, **NOT** the bottom layout guide (which is the `UIPageControl` in your case).

On the contrary, `V:[button][bottomLayoutGuide]` will constrain the view to the `UIPageController`'s `UIPageControl`, which probably has a default size of 50, which is why there is a difference between those two.

I hope that made things clear.

Comment: that sounds really, really good - thanks a lot for the perfect explanation!